# JSP send DTO file along with jsp modelAttribute to spring in Jquery

Tags: jquery, spring, jsp

here am trying to send my form modelAttribute along with DTO file to spring controller, but the DTO is null in controller.
Actually my modelAttribute 'myForm' contains field values and along with I need to send few more data to controller hence instead of sending individually I set the values in DTO file and send it. Can you please help me on this. Thanks in Advance. Below are my code details,

```
<form:form name="myForm" modelAttribute="item">

var values = $("#item").serialize();
var dto = $("customDto").serialize();
    dto = {
        type : "New Item",
        userId : userId,
        status : "New",
    };

    $.ajax({
        type : "post",
        data : values + "&dto=" + dto,
        url : "/myApp/submit.do",
        success : function(msg) {
            jQuery("#msg").html("Form submitted");
        }
    });
```

Spring Controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/submit")
public ModelAndView submitForm(
    @ModelAttribute("item") Item item,@ModelAttribute("dto") CustomDto customDto) {
    //Logic
  return model;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use one `ModelAttribute`, For this create a mapper class 
with the 2 objects inside (item and DTO), then put modelattribute for this mapper

```
     @RequestMapping(value = "/submit")
                    public ModelAndView submitForm(
                            @ModelAttribute MapperClass mapper) {
        ...               

                    }



      Class MapperClass {
        //Put all fields here which is sending from UI to controller

    private Item item;
private CustomDto customDto;
//create getters and setters

        }
```

Comment: Thanks Vipin, sry seems my questions confused. Here am trying to send DTO and modelAttribute from JSP to controller.

Comment: Then you can use a mapper class which has all fields in DTO and what ever things you want to send from jsp to controller and then `@ModelAttribute object` in controller method will resolve the issue

Comment: Thx Vipin, am getting bad request 400 error, below is my updated code,

Comment: @RequestMapping(value = "/submit")
 public ModelAndView submitSell(@ModelAttribute("dto") CustomDto customDto) {
  ---logics-----
  return model;
 }

Comment: var values = $("#item").serialize();
var dto = $("customDto").serialize();
   dto = {
    type : "New Item",
                                userId : userId,
                                 status : "New",
    tradeitem : values
   };
 $.ajax({
        type : "post",
        data : dto,
        url : "/myApp/submit.do",
        success : function(msg) {
            jQuery("#msg").html("Form submitted");
        }
    });

Comment: Here in my CustomDto I have added Item modelAttribute and other values.

Comment: @user3016821 but by doing that you are modifying a class only for this request which is not a good practice. Use mappers instead which is only for particluar request.